# Trouble multiplying and dividing in Python

Tags: python, multiplication

So I'm writing a game for a competition.

Up until this point, the user has entered a number.

```
if user % 2 == 0 : 

    print("What you entered is an even number.")
    print("")

    print("So, according to RULE 1, we must now divide it by 2.")

    int(user)/ 2
    thing2 = "So, now we're left with " + str(user) + "."

    print (thing2)
else : 

    print("What you entered is an odd number.")
    print("")

    print("So, according to RULE 1, we must now multiply it by 3, and add 1.")

    int(user) * 3
    user += 1

    thing2 = "So, now we're left with " + str(user) + "."
    print (thing2)
```

.... But the `int(user) * 3` part doesn't actually multiply the number by 3, but it does add one.

For the record, I've tried loads of possibilities like just having `user * 3` (without the int() thing there) and I'm a beginner at Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to say:

`user = int(user)*3`

This makes the value of user the original times by 3. Before, you didn't do anything to the value of the multiplication. You need to save the value in a variable

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the output of that statement:

```
user = int(user) * 3
```

You may want to change user to an integer in the beginning so you don't need to keep doing it, something like:

```
user = int(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

`int(user) * 3` and `int(user)/2` *return* a value, but this value is not *assigned*. So you have to do

```
user = user * 3
```

and

```
user = user / 2
```

As pointed out by jonrsharpe in the comments, the `int()` appearing in your code is something more complicated than I'd thought. Since during the equality check `user` is already a number, you're either simply doing something unnecessary out of confusion or trying to convert floating point to integer (if I recall correctly, in python 3.x division converts integers to floats by default). If it's the latter, you should do `user = int(user / 2)` or better yet, `user = user // 2` (again thanks to jonrsharpe).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to change it earlier on to save time later on.

Comment: It must already be a number, otherwise your check for evenness wouldn't work (it would be interpreted as an old-style string formatting).

Comment: @Dunno note that `//` is integer division in both 2.x and 3.x

Comment: @jonrsharpe huh, I wasn't aware of that operator. I learn something new about python almost every day!